# Per model file to persist data in loopbackjs

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have this in my `datasources.json`

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory",
    "file": "storage/dbdata.json"
  }
}
```

and everything works fine. But I see it dumps all data in one single file which I don't want. Is there any way that I can generate per model data dump file like above which will automatically imported during app bootup process?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup as many datasources in the `datasources.json` file as needed. You can then connect your model to a specific data source as per the instructions listed [here](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/datasources.json)